# How To Scroll To A Specific Widget in Flutter Using SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have a MainScreen and SecondScreen. When the drawer item in the MainScreen clicked. It should move to SecondScreen Container widget. But how to do that?

I have set ScrollController for SecondScreen SingleChildScrollView. but how to move to a certain widget?

1. Create a method in SecondScreen which scroll to the widget?
2. What if I have 3rd screen which need same functionality.

**SecondScreen.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
  var containerKey = GlobalKey();
class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  final Key widgetKey;

  const SecondScreen({Key key, this.widgetKey}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SecondScreen> createState() => _SecondScreenState();
}

class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {

@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
Scrollable.ensureVisible(
    widget.widgetKey,
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
    curve: Curves.easeInOut,
);
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: scrollController,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text('hi'),
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              height: 1000,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              height: 1000,
            ),
            Container(
              key: containerKey,
              color: Colors.green,
              height: 1000,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**mainscreen.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:stackoverflow_check/scrollcheck/second_screen.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => SecondScreen(widgetKey: containerKey),
                  ),
                );
                //scrollController.an
              },
              child: Text('click'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Main screen

```
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => SecondScreen(widgetNum: 2),
                  ),
                );
                //scrollController.an
              },
              child: Text('click'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

SecondScreen

```
class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final int widgetNum;
  const SecondScreen({Key? key, required this.widgetNum}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SecondScreen> createState() => _SecondScreenState();
}

class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {
  ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
  var containerKey = GlobalKey();
  var container2Key = GlobalKey();
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    // TODO: implement didChangeDependencies
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
      if (widget.widgetNum == 1) {
        Scrollable.ensureVisible(
          containerKey.currentContext!,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
          curve: Curves.easeInOut,
        );
      } else {
        Scrollable.ensureVisible(
          container2Key.currentContext!,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
          curve: Curves.easeInOut,
        );
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: scrollController,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text('hi'),
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              height: 1000,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              height: 1000,
            ),
            Container(
              key: containerKey,
              color: Colors.green,
              height: 1000,
            ),
            Container(
              key: container2Key,
              color: Colors.blue,
              height: 1000,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I want to move to a container widget which have key.

Comment: edited answer. Please use Scrollable.ensureVisible

Comment: where to use Scrollable.ensureVisible()? while tapping the drawer item?

Comment: Pass the widgets key to screen 2. In initstate of screen 2 use the method that i sent and replace the key.. it should scroll to the desired widget

Comment: i don't get context from the key.

Comment: i have updated my question with updated code.

Comment: Did the above code work?

Comment: nope. I don't get the context from key. in Scrollable.ensureVisible(

Comment: Edited my answer. tested also and its working. change the widgetNum value in home to 1 or2 and it will scroll to the respective widget

Comment: Did the code work?

Comment: @Mahi make sure you are setting the key property on each container.